# Cross-browser solution to work with SVG files?

Tags: javascript, flash, svg, raphael

What cross-browser JavaScript SVG library will allow me to display and interact with ***pre-made*** SVG images.

I know of these libraries:

- [**Raphaël**](http://raphaeljs.com/): I'm currently using this along with a SVG loading plugin. But that plugin does not support Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator SVGs (i.e. most SVGs).
- [**cang**](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/): This library looks promising, but it requires `<canvas>` support, which IE doesn't have natively.
- [**svgweb**](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/): Another more-promising library. It requires Flash, but most IE users have Flash.
- [**jQuery SVG**](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html): It seems to be able to load SVG images, but development seems to have died. And it requires me to use a modified version of jQuery 1.3.

I'm basically trying to make chunks of arbitrary images "selectable".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raphaël *does* support importing of Illustrator SVGs, through the use of [this great plugin](https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import). All you have to do is save your ai file as an SVG, open it up using a text editor, copy out the code and import it with the plugin. Works great, except : only supports "path" objects, no text, no gradients, no shadows...

Comment: I'm actually using it right now. It doesn't work very well, sadly, and fails for my exported Illustrator image quite badly (I get a black rectangle instead of the actual shape).

Comment: It does have limitations with complex SVG files. Could you post the SVG file you're using?

Comment: The problem is with the two first elements of the SVG file : they are rect items. The plugin only supports paths. If you delete them out, it works.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out a few hours ago :P Thank you Chrome's Inspector. I'm just trying to manipulate the SVGs to join paths. I guess I *can* use Raphael!

Comment: By the way, you can avoid the whole "cut the code, paste the code" step by using jQuery and Ajax to load the SVG file directly and then passing the SVG markup to the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/ for Canvas support in IE and Cang for SVG suport using Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a combo of cang and svgweb, you could check to see if the browser allows canvases, and if so, load cang and use it. Otherwise check if they have flash, and if so, use svgweb. If they have neither, then tell them to upgrade their browser.

You could read http://ejohn.org/blog/future-proofing-javascript-libraries/ if you are unsure about javascript feature detection.

Comment: I might have to do this, sadly. But I'm not really thrilled about re-writing a ton of code to work with two libraries, but if that's what it takes, then I'll have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to make use of [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) (an IE plug-in). This will save you maintaining two sets of code (one for IE users, another for regular browser users). Adding the following meta-tag to your page will enable SVG to render in IE (via GCF):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

[See here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started#TOC-Detecting-Google-Chrome-Frame-and-P) for instructions how to detect, and potentially prompt the user to install GCF.

Comment: I thought about GCF, but it'd be hard to get any IE users to install it. I'd prefer something that can run out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to use Raphael along with [this tool](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE90.php), which allows you to convert SVG files (generated by Illustrator, in my case) to Raphael code almost as-is. And since Raphael is IE6+ - you could easily be crossbrowsy with some effort on your part.

[Here](http://vms-print.ru) is my example of what can be achieved with a combination of these two things.